# Package is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have ported one of my libraries to net core. It works fine from a netcore 2.2 web app. Now I want to package it with nuget. I use the folder convention way.

I have tried

lib/netcore/mylib.dll

lib/netstandard2.0/mylib.dll

lib/netcoreapp2.2

But I only get
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

edit: Nuget explorer seems to look allright? Whats going on? :/ Why is it saying netcore version 0.0?
[image]

edit: nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy</id>
    <version>2.0.165</version>
    <authors>Anders Malmgren</authors>
    <owners>Anders Malmgren</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl>http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy</projectUrl>
    <description>A Event Aggregator proxy for SignalR</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013-2019</copyright>
    <tags>SignalR EventAggregator Proxy</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.2">
        <dependency id="SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Constraint" version="1.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" version="1.1.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Can you please post .nuspec file as well.

Comment: no problem its added

Comment: Found problem, cache problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this. Nuget keeps a cache. So even if you use a temporary local nuget folder for testing, it will use the cache, so if the cached one contains  error (in my case a lib/netcore) it will not update.

Fixed by clearing cache

%userprofile%.nuget\packages